# Get pixel locations of the joints in the depth and in the RGB images

Tags: python, depth, kinect-v2, openkinect, pykinect

l have skeleton data of 15 joints per person. Each person  is described with 
(X,Y,Z) coordinates.

Give that coordinates, l would like to find the pixel locations in the depth and in the RGB images.

How can l get that  ?

Is there any Kinect functions (**in linux**) such as :

```
SkeletonToDepthImage()
NuiTransformSkeletonToDepthImage()
NuiTransform()
```